# Reader does not copy css for certain epub file, how can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, epub

I am trying to understand how the FolioReader algorithm works. One problem which I have come across is that it does not copy the css for certain files when it loads it to the web view.

This is the algorithm I am using:

https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android

A certain case I am working with has the following problem: It loads the file, however some titles which are centred are moved to the left.

Comment: The top two bullet-points on that page are "_Custom fonts_" and "_Custom text sizes_" implying (to me) it can (to some degree or other) override formatting in eBook. You would need to look its documentation to see if/how you can control this, and/or dig deeper into why some files are affected and not others.

Comment: After some poking I narrowed it down to the css.file. If all h1,h2,h3... elements of the file are commented out, most misaligned elements return to the position which they are suppose to be in, but there are still few which are out of place.